# I am depressed... No one wants me

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> I am depressed...
> No one wants me.
>
> You can take test,
> You can do management,
> You can also use the force to get the answer,
> But the force alone wont help you get the answer,
> Always alone,
> But once in a while, I have lone friend,
> Together with him I can achieve great things.

Comment: I want to edit the dPressed so hard I'm depressed myself because *probably* I shouldn't since it seems to be part of the puzzle...

Comment: @MiquelColl :) go on edit it... I think it can also provide a clue....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> Stress?

I am depressed...

> Stress Depression, also the symbol for stress σ looks like a ***"d"pressed***(Credit to Ankoganit)

No one wants me.

> Sure thing

You can take test,

> Stress test

You can do management,

> Stress Management

You can also use the force to get the answer,
But the force alone wont help you get the answer,

> Edit: Stress = Force / Area (Credit to Nij)

Always alone,
But once in a while, I have lone friend,
Together with him I can achieve great things.

> (hints from OP) Strain, where E = stress / strain (Young's Modulus)?

Comment: spot on... you got the answer, first four lines are correct. Figure out rest, and I will accept the answer

Comment: Alex, perhaps consider synonyms for your answer in an engineering context.

Comment: Isn't stress' friend adrenaline?

Comment: One remark: the usual symbol for stress is $\sigma$, which looks like a **d** with its antenna **pressed** down, hence the initial clue "dPressed" (which was edited later on). It's somewhat stretch though.

Comment: dPressed or bFallen

Comment: Yup, got the force one correct!! last three lines need a little more work

Comment: @smriti I wonder if the last 2 lines' a ref to Stress, or Force?

Comment: well you got all of explanation except last one correct, so here is a hint : think young :)

Comment: @smriti updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You might be

> Work

I am depressed...
No one wants me.

> Many people don't like to work.

You can take test,
You can do management,

> These are jobs at which one can work.

You can also use the force to get the answer,
But the force alone wont help you get the answer,

> Work = Force * Distance
>  Force is part of the formula for work, but isn't the only factor.

Always alone,
But once in a while, I have lone friend,
Together with him I can achieve great things.

> Work/Time = Power
>  In this case, when work is no longer alone, with time as his friend, they make power, which can be used to achieve great things.

Comment: Also, there was an early typo of "dpressed", which OP said "could also provide a clue". With d = distance and pressed = pushed = applied force, one could see 'dpressed' as a clue for 'distance * force'.

Comment: good explanation but not an answer

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is
can take test

> [in this link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions)

can do mangement

> [in this link](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/)

Together with him I can achieve great things

> earning reputation points.

force to get answer

> Move the mouse pointer to spoilers to see answer.

force alone wont help you get the answer

> sometimes answers are wrong

But once in a while, I have lone friend

> can't be online whole day..

so the answer is

> puzzling in stack exchange.

Comment: sorry, not an answer, interesting explanation though.

Comment: It is not related to stack exchange, hint is on its way. Also.. your answer doesn't give any information about "I am depressed...No one wants me."

Comment: "puzzling in stack exchange" is a thing we all want : )

Comment: @smriti i thought you were sad , and found happiness puzzling in stack exchange

Comment: hahaha, okok, no these lines are also part of the puzzle